# I cannot pass data retrieved from API back out to the callback passed to app.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I've retrieved data from the github api. I then want to send it to the client.

I'm passing a callback that successfully receives the data but **I don't know how to pass that retrieved data back out to the callback** passed to the get method so that it can be passed to the client

I fear this is a really naive callback confusion so I'm very grateful for the advice

```
let GitHubApi = require('github'),
    http = require('http'),
    express = require('express')

let app = express();
app.listen(3000)

let github = new GitHubApi({
  version: '3.0.0'
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  getUserData("jeresig", whatWeDoWithResults)
  res.send(???)
})

function getUserData (username, callback){
  github.search.users({q: username},function(err,data){
    if (err) {
      console.log('error', err);
    }
    else {
      callback(data)
    }
  })
}

function whatWeDoWithResults (results){
  console.log(results)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass data to the callback, and the callback will send them:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  getUserData("jeresig", function(results){
    res.send(results)
  })  
})
```